# python code for callculation of total worked time of an employee from a given database

Tags: sql, python-2.7

### help me

I have 3 column [empid in integer, flag in integer(1 for in,0 for out) & datetime in string format(i.e. u'Thu, 03 Oct 2013 17:35:43 +0000)]
    I want to know how write the code or algorithm to get in_time & out_time for a certain date using variable count. That-means, when count is even, it will give me in_time & when count will increase it will give me out_time for odd. here some code i have tried.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/Documents/attendance_report/data.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('select * from attendance where emp = 95')
count = 0

for row in c:
   count +=1
   print row
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the builtin `enumerate` to keep track of the index.

```
for index, row in enumerate(c):
    if index%2 == 0: # Odd numbered row (since index starts from 0)
        # row contains out_time
        print row
    else:
        # row contains in_time
        print row
```